# Accessing DrawerStatus From Sibling Component

Tags: react-native, expo, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-drawer

My main app contains a `NavigationContainer` with a `Drawer.Navigator` that houses its  `Drawer.Screen` components.

Outside of the `Navigator`, I have a floating action button component within the `NavigationContainer` that I'd like to conditionally render based on if the navigation drawer is open.

```js
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()

export default function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer ...>
          
          <Drawer.Navigator ...>
            <Drawer.Screen ... />
            <Drawer.Screen ... />
            <Drawer.Screen ... />
           
          </Drawer.Navigator>
          
          <FloatingActionButton />
           
        </NavigationContainer>
      )
    }
}
```

Since I can't use `useDrawerStatus` within the `FloatingActionButton` component because the component isn't a child of `Drawer.Navigator` (which can't house the button itself, because `Navigator` can only contain `Screen`, `Group`, and `Fragment` components), how can I listen to the drawer status or otherwise access its current open state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [screenListeners](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/#screenlisteners-prop-on-the-navigator) prop to listen to `state` event and check if `drawer` is present. Something like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [isDrawerOpen, setIsDrawerOpen] = useState(false)

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator 
        screenListeners={{
          state: (e) => {
            setIsDrawerOpen(e.data.state.history.some((it) => it.type === 'drawer'))
          }
        }}>
...
      </Drawer.Navigator>
      {!isDrawerOpen && <FloatingActionButton/>}
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

Comment: Looks like `screenListeners` is exactly the piece I was missing! What should `e` be typecast to in typescript to access `state.history`?